# Align checkbox labels above box

Tags: html, css, checkbox, alignment, label

Need to do something like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/RhR8w.jpg numbers above box ideally so that they stay aligned across browsers and devices.

Thanks

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you share your HTML and CSS?

Answer (score -1):

You could do this with a table layout easily.

```
<table>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Bedrooms</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td></td>
   <td>1</td>
   <td>2</td>
   <td>3</td>
   <td>4</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
   <td>Bathrooms</td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
   <td><input type="checkbox" /></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

And as far as the styling goes, just do

```
td {
  text-align: center;
}
```

to make it look exactly as you want it.

Comment: Not accessibility friendly. Adding labels mapped to each input could help but I don't think a table is necessary.